# Count dentro de um array com valores de outro array

Tags: python

Gostaria de realizar um count dos valores contidos dentro do `array1` com os valores do array `nomes`, porém ele está me retornando uma saída com os valores estranhos

**SCRIPT**

```
array1 = [
'VALUE1',
'VALUE1',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE3',
'VALUE4',
'VALUE5',
]

nomes = ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2']

for valores in array1:
        for linha in nomes:
                print(valores.count(linha))
```

**OUTPUT**

> 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

**OUTPUT DESEJADO**

> 2 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não precisa de dois `for` a não ser que vá contar 'manualmente' - sem usar o méotodo `.count`.

O mais correto é chamar o método  `.count` do array1, passando cada palavra que deseja contar lá

```py
array1 = [
'VALUE1',
'VALUE1',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE3',
'VALUE4',
'VALUE5',
]

nomes = ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2']

for linha in nomes:
        print(array1.count(linha))
```

Do jeito que você está fazendo, está contanto a ocorrência da palavra na lista "nomes" dentro de *cada palavra*  do "array1". (Strings também são sequências, por isso tem o método "count")

Isso aí funciona, mas não é o melhor jeito - ja que vai percorrer o array1 uma vez para cada palavra buscada - não vai fazer diferença nenhuma para um caso só com algumas linhas, e num programa que roda uma vez só - o tempo deve ser inferior a 10 milisegundos. Mas se isso acontece numa aplicação Web em que o tempo de resposta seja crítico, pode começar a fazer diferença.

O ideal é um algoritmo que percorra toda a lista inicial (array1) apenas uma vez, e já vá contando os valores de todas as chaves que encontrar. O Python tem a classe `collections.Counter` que pode fazer isso de uma vez - mas para entender melhor o algoritmo:

```py
array1 = ...
nomes = {'VALUE1': 0, 'VALUE2': 0}

for frase in array1:
   if frase in nomes:
       nomes[frase] += 1

print(nomes)
```

(As duas formas até aqui são só se o match de "nomes" for pra linha inteira do "array1" - se o valor em "nomes" for apenas uma parte da frase em "array1" tem que criar algo usando dois "for"  mesmo - ou transferindo um "for" para uma regular expression)

Answer (score 4):

O Python tem um função nativa chamada `Count()` que, como o nome já diz, faz contas.

Assim é muito mais simples rodar ela dentro de um for para cada um dos itens da sua lista `nomes`e printar a quantidade dos mesmos. Olha como ficou bem mais curto e simples o seu código:

```
array1 = [
'VALUE1',
'VALUE1',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE3',
'VALUE4',
'VALUE5',
]

nomes = ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2']

for x in nomes:
  print(array1.count(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

esse metodo funciona , tem esse site que tem algums outros metodos pra python talvez ajude https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/325708_d9b07b07bf2b4bc8803ba6d53d834eeb.html

```
array1 = ['VALUE1','VALUE1','VALUE2','VALUE2','VALUE2','VALUE3','VALUE4','VALUE5',]
nomes = ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2']
value1 = 0
value2 = 0
x= 0
while x < len(array1):
    if array1[x] == nomes[0]:
        value1= value1+1
    elif array1[x] == nomes[1]:
        value2= value2+1
    x= x+1
print(f'o Numero de {nomes[0]} = {value1} \no Numero de {nomes[1]} = {value2}')
```

Tambem existe o metodo Counts

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que ao fazer `for valores in array1:` você está percorrendo os valores dessa lista, passando para a variável `valores` uma string. Para obter o output desejado, faça dessa seguinte forma:

```
array1 = [
'VALUE1',
'VALUE1',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE2',
'VALUE3',
'VALUE4',
'VALUE5',
]

nomes = ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2']

for linha in nomes:
    print(array1.count(linha))
```

No código que você fez, você está contando quantas vezes uma sub-string aparecia nas strings contidas na lista `array1`. No código que eu fiz, estou contando quantas vezes a string `linha` aparece no `array1`.

Comment: Só agora que eu percebi que me deram negativo por nenhum motivo....